# how to remove the title slide from Rstudio ioslides presentation

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, ioslides

I am using R Studio and R Markdown to create an ioslides presentation. I would like to eliminate the title slide, and begin the presentation with a normal slide. So far, I have tried removing the title from the YAML options, but this just results in a blank title page.

#### How can I remove the title page altogether?

my YAML options

```
---
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    widescreen: true
---
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to customise the template file. You can find the path of the default one in your system by typing `rmarkdown:::rmarkdown_system_file("rmd/ioslides/default.html")` in the console.

The easiest way to play with it would be to copy it to the directory of your project, rename it and put additional YAML option like `template: custom_template.html`. Even though this might not be enough to remove the title slide completely, you can always customise it so it looks like the first slide of your presentation.